# js confirm closes when we switch tab in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript confirm in my web page. Actually My problem is , when I try to switch the tab in chrome at the time of confirm dialog displays the confirm dialog get closed. Is there any possible way to stay the confirm dialog even when I try to switch the tab?. This is happening in chrome.

Comment: I'm testing `window.confirm()` in Chrome, if I change tab and then switch back, I still can see the confirm window.

Comment: window.confirm() is working when I try to run it in console. If I run in code window.confirm() too has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description I have got 2 scenarios,

1. You want to keep the confirm dialogue open if a user switch chrome tab and then returns to the tab again, you can use alert for this, alert remains there until you shift a tab also it shows a dot on tab as well which keeps user aware of some notification is there waiting for him.

   alert('Some content here');
2. You want to restrict user to shift window until clicks on the confirm button. For this you can do something like on changing the data of your page you can keep track of unsaved changes and while user is shifting tab you can restrict him using below code,

let unsaved = false;

```
const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  unsaved = true;
});


const unloadPage = () => {
   if (unsaved) {
     return "You have unsaved changes on this page.";
   }
};

window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage;
```

Also, if you want you can search for Prompt as well may be it would be helpful as well if above scenarios are not of your type.